# List slices: Why the difference of output of these two similar code snippets?

Tags: python

What is happening in these two simple lines of code?

I guess it is storing the print function as a part of the variable.

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[-2:-7:-1])
```

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], print(a[-2:-7:-1])
```

Comment: The comma in the second statement is turning `a` into a `tuple`.  So yes, your assumption is on the right track.  But, when run alone an error should be thrown as `a` is not yet defined. Since `print` does not have a return statement, the second element of the tuple `a` will be `None`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure your question is clear. You can start by explaining what happens when you try the code, what you thought should happen instead, and how that is different. Then clearly ask a question based on your confusion, starting with a word like "what" or "why", and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: to get the same result from both pices of code, replace the `,` in the second one with a `;`, that acts the same as using a newline, although it's not recommended for readability.

Comment: You should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://xyproblem.info/ and make sure you actually understand the question you are asking about. For example, is it actually necessary to do any list slicing, in order to cause the behaviour that confuses you? Or is it just something that happens with any calculation, depending on whether you put the `print` on the same line or not?

Comment: Are you sure the comma is correct? A semi-colon might make more sense there

Answer (score 0):

This is two statements:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[-2:-7:-1])
```

This is one statement. Let me add the implicit parentheses:

```
# a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], print(a[-2:-7:-1])
a = (
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
    print(a[-2:-7:-1])
)
```

If `a` was previously declared and assigned a value, then the `print()` function would still execute properly, `([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], None)` would get assigned to `a` (because the return value of `print()` is `None`).

If `a` hadn't been declared and assigned yet, then you'd get an error on this line saying as much.